# how to remove confliction between jquery-1.7.2.min.js and jquery-1.9.0.min.js in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have to put both of these (jquery-1.7.2.min.js and jquery-1.9.0.min.js) in single aspx page.
The jquery-1.9.0.min.js is used for slideshow. If I put jquery-1.7.2.min.js in the same page slideshow doesn't work. But for Some different work i must want jquery-1.7.2.min.js.

Can anyone remove the conflict between these two jquery???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: Thank you to guide me :) @Uwe Keim